# JAVA HW. Not able to interact with created JFrame GUI until program is finished

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

I have a few JFrame GUIs I created for my program; one with a menu and display of an output.txt file, and the other to enter information.

I can not interact or "click" on them until the program is totally done running.

I thought it was the JOption panes (Yes/No) taking precedence over the JFrames, however, I commented out all the JOption panes in my program to test this, and you still have to wait till the program is totally finished to access the JFrames.

[image]

```
    public class TheList extends JPanel {


public TheList(){

}
public static void List(){


ArrayList<Food> didntBuy = new ArrayList<Food>();
ArrayList<Food> arrayList = new ArrayList<Food>();// creating an ArrayList for Food objects. 
ArrayList<Food> sortLow = new ArrayList<Food>();// creating ArrayLists for high, medium, and low priorities. 
ArrayList<Food> sortMed = new ArrayList<Food>();
ArrayList<Food> sortHigh = new ArrayList<Food>();
final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
//System.out.println("\nEnter your name");
String yourName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\nEnter your name for the list");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\nYou entered: "+ yourName);
boolean checkLetterFirstName;
checkLetterFirstName = CheckInput.CheckForNumber(yourName);// Used this class from another student.
if(checkLetterFirstName == true) 
{ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I'm sorry but no numbers or spaces can be in your first name.", yourName, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
//System.out.println("Enter you name");
// yourName=keyboard.nextLine();
yourName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\nEnter your name");
checkLetterFirstName = CheckInput.CheckForNumber(yourName);}
try{
//System.out.println("Enter funds");    
//Food.currentCash=keyboard.nextDouble();
String fn=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter funds for the list");
Food.currentCash= Double.parseDouble(fn);// converting String to a Double. 

if(Food.getCurrentCash()<0)

    throw new Exception("Exception: no negative numbers");

}
catch (Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (e.getMessage()), null, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter postive numbers only");
    String fn=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter funds for the list");
    Food.currentCash= Double.parseDouble(fn);


}

Food.currentCash1=Food.currentCash;

NumberFormat formatter=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
System.out.println("Current Cash");
System.out.println(formatter.format(Food.currentCash));// used a currency formatter to covert to dollars.

final Scanner keyboard6 = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    //An abstract class cannot be instantiated



int answer=
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to add a new apple(s) object to list?", "Click Yes or No:", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (answer== JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                {


                JFrame frame = new JFrame();  // creating a new JFrame object called "frame".
                Container pane = null;
                // SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
                BoxLayout layout= new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);


                JTextArea text0 =new JTextArea("Do you want to add an apple(s) to list?");  //creating a new TextArea object called "text". 
                frame.setSize(600, 600); //setting width and hight of window frame. 
                JButton yes = new JButton("Yes");
                JButton no = new JButton("No");
                JButton enter= new JButton("Enter");
                JButton enter2= new JButton("Enter");
                JButton enter3= new JButton("Enter");
                JButton enter4= new JButton("Enter");

                yes.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                no.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                final JPanel panel = new JPanel();  // creating 4 new panels
                final JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
                final JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
                final JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();


                JLabel label = new JLabel("What kind of apple?"); // creating 4 labels per panel. 
                JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Enter priority or -1 to exit program.");
                JLabel label3 = new JLabel ("Enter price you want to pay.");
                JLabel label4 = new JLabel ("Enter quanity.");

                JTextField text = new JTextField(10);
                JTextField text2 = new JTextField(10);
                JTextField text3 = new JTextField(10);
                JTextField text4 = new JTextField(10);

                panel.add(label);// adding labels to the panel
                panel2.add(label2);
                panel3.add(label3);
                panel4.add(label4);

                panel.add(text); // adding text fields to each panel to enter information. 
                panel2.add(text2);
                panel3.add(text3);
                panel4.add(text4);

                panel.add(enter);
                panel2.add(enter2);
                panel3.add(enter3);
                panel4.add(enter4);
                panel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                panel2.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                panel3.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                panel4.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);// ends program if closed. 
                frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true); // on top of other windows. 
                frame.setTitle("Apple");
                //Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\joey zasa\\workspace\\homework4\\src\\homework4\\apple-full2.jpg"));

                frame.add(text0);

                frame.add(yes);
                frame.add(no);


                frame.add(panel);
                frame.getContentPane().add(panel2);
                frame.getContentPane().add(panel3);
                frame.getContentPane().add(panel4);
                addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
                final Fruit appleObject =new apple();

                yes.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                        panel.setVisible(true);

                    panel2.setVisible(true);
                        panel3.setVisible(true);
                        panel4.setVisible(true);

                    } 


                });

                no.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        panel.setVisible(false);
                        panel2.setVisible(false);
                        panel3.setVisible(false);
                        panel4.setVisible(false);


                    }

                });

                enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    appleObject.setName(keyboard6.nextLine());

                    }


                });

                enter2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    appleObject.setPriority(keyboard.nextInt());

                    }


                });

                enter3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        appleObject.setPrice(keyboard.nextDouble());

                    }


                });

                enter3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try{
                            System.out.println("Enter quanity");
                            appleObject.setQuanity(keyboard.nextInt());
                            if(appleObject.getQuanity()<0)
                                throw new negativeException();
                            }
                            catch (negativeException x) {
                                System.out.println(x.getMessage());
                                System.out.println("Enter quanity again");
                                appleObject.setQuanity(keyboard.nextInt());

                            }

                    }


                });

                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);// setting the visibility of the frame to true. 

                for (int z=0; z<appleObject.getQuanity(); z++){
                        arrayList.add (appleObject);
                        i++;
                }}

       if( appleObject.getPriority()==1||appleObject.getPriority()==2){
                    sortHigh.add(appleObject);}// adding only               one instance of an Object to one of 3 Arraylists
                    if(       appleObject.getPriority()==3||appleObject.getPriority()==4){
                        sortMed.add(appleObject);}
                    if( appleObject.getPriority()==5){
                        sortLow.add(appleObject);}

                }
                    System.out.println("\n"+yourName+"'s list:");
int listSize=arrayList.size();
for(int position=0; position <listSize; position++){
    System.out.println(arrayList.get(position));
}


int y = arrayList.size();
System.out.println("\nSize of list: "+y+"\n" );

    // Sorting with low, medium,100 high, needs. Priorities 1-2=high, 3-4=medium, 5= low.                                                   

System.out.println("\nHigh priority items :\n");
int listHigh=sortHigh.size();
for(int position=0; position <listHigh; position++){
    System.out.println(sortHigh.get(position));
}
System.out.println("\nMedium priority items :\n");
int listMed=sortMed.size();
for(int position=0; position <listMed; position++){
    System.out.println(sortMed.get(position));

}

System.out.println("\nLow priority items :\n");
int listLow=sortLow.size();
for(int position=0; position <listLow; position++){
    System.out.println(sortLow.get(position));
}
  System.out.println("\n\nCash left for virtual list: ");
  System.out.println(formatter.format(Food.currentCash));
  System.out.println("\n\nCash left after real world prices: ");
  System.out.println(formatter.format(Food.currentCash1));

  String nameofFile="out.txt";
  PrintWriter outputStream=null;
   try{
outputStream=new PrintWriter(nameofFile);   
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException e)
  { 
System.out.println("Error opening file");
System.exit(0);
  }

        {
       outputStream.println("\n"+yourName+"'s list of purchased Items:");
      int listSize4=arrayList.size();
     for(int position=0; position <listSize4; position++){
    outputStream.println(arrayList.get(position));
}
    outputStream.println("\nHigh priority items :\n");
    int listHigh1=sortHigh.size();
    for(int position=0; position <listHigh; position++){
        outputStream.println(sortHigh.get(position));
    }
    outputStream.println("\nMedium priority items :\n");
    int listMed1=sortMed.size();
    for(int position=0; position <listMed1; position++){
        outputStream.println(sortMed.get(position));    
    }

    outputStream.println("\nLow priority items :\n");
    int listLow1=sortLow.size();
    for(int position=0; position <listLow; position++){
        outputStream.println(sortLow.get(position));
    }
        outputStream.println("\nItems you did not buy, but you may need: \n");
        int listDidntBuy=didntBuy.size();
        for(int position=0; position <listDidntBuy; position++){
            outputStream.println(didntBuy.get(position));


    }
    outputStream.close();  

    }
    }
        }
     private static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
    {
        pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


    }
  }
     }
```

My program has too many classes provide you with a small program, sorry. This is the class I am creating one of the GUIs in. Its the small GUI called "apple". The GUI behind apple in the picture is from another class and opened in Main. I also edited out the rest of the "grocery list objects" only including "apple".

Comment: *"Ill post code if requested."* That would probably be wise...better yet a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be blocking the Event Dispatching Thread with some kind of long running process or infinite loop

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: thanks, I ended up redesigning my program. I started with a menu GUI and ran everything from there.